# kibana vega (formula) tranformed object results in blank page

Tags: kibana, vega-lite, kibana-7

I am trying to invert the data I receive from my elastic search query.
The data I have is from a neural network driven car on a track.
I have track locations in X and Z, and the performance.. :

```
data: {
    url: {
        %context%: true
        // %timefield%: @timestamp
        index: performance.capture.August.*
        body: {
            size: 10000,
            _source: ["var_Track_X", "var_Track_Z", "var_Performance"]
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried to use calculate instead of tyle and expr, but no luck,
I tried to add _source. infront of my property name, but no luck either..

kibana would allow me to create scripted fields, but since vega can't
use these I need to make my own.

so I am trying:

```
transform: [
     {type: "formula", expr: "-1 * datum.var_Track_X", as: "var_Playercar_X_Flipped"}
]
```

and plugging it in the axis like:

```
encoding: {
  x: {
    // Draw the time field on the x-axis in temporal mode (i.e. as a time axis)
    field: var_Playercar_X_Flipped
    type: quantitative
    // Hide the axis label for the x-axis
    axis: { title: false }
}
```

anyone know why it's not finding my property?

Comment: I've never seen ``"type": "formula"`` or ``expr`` as a transform key in a Vega-Lite spec. Is that a kibana thing? What is it you are trying to do? Consider including a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you wish to have useful answers to your question.

Comment: no, just vega. https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/formula/
I'm trying to run the expression. so I can invert my data  var_Track_X.